# The proper name for a kind of ordered space

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology, order-theory, linear-orders

I'm trying to find the correct term for a specific kind of totally ordered space:

Let $S$ be a totally ordered space with strict total order $<$.

Property: For any two $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ in $S$ where $s_1 < s_2$, there must exist some $s_{3}$ such that $s_{1} < s_{3}$ and $s_{3} < s_{2}$.

What is the name of this property?  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Dense order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order) is one name that concept goes by.